# How did pro + curare semantically shift to mean 'cause, effect'?

Tags: etymology, latin

[Lexico's definition of 'procure'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/procure)

> [image]

[Etymonline on 'procure (v.)'](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=resent&searchmode=none):

> c.1300, "bring about, cause, effect,"
>   from Old French *procurer* "care for, be occupied with; bring about, cause; acquire, provide" (13c.) and directly from Late Latin *procurare* "manage, take care of;"
>   from ***pro-*** `"in behalf of"` (see [pro-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pro-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + ***curare*** "care for" (see [cure (v.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cure&allowed_in_frame=0)).
>
> Main modern sense "obtain; recruit" (late 14c.) is via "take pains to get" (mid-14c.). Meaning "to obtain (women) for sexual gratification" is attested from c.1600. Related: *Procured; procuring*.

1. What semantic notions underlie "in behalf of" + "care for" with "bring about, cause, effect" ?
2. Why was **pro-*** upheld as the prefix?
3. This hypothetical can unveil why ***pro-*** baffles me. Imagine a comatose patient (C) who has appointed an attorney-in-fact (A) (by a Power of Attorney). If A cares `in behalf of` C, then why does C need

   - 'persuade or cause (someone) to do something' (Lexico's Definition 2)
   - or 'cause (something) to happen' (Definition 2.1)?

C already has the Power of Attorney!  C's clearly acting alone.

Comment: The prefix *pro-* has several derived meanings from its basic meaning: **forward**. The root *cure* has several derived meanings from its basic meaning: **concern**. In *procure*, one derived meaning of pro-: **in behalf of** joins with one derived meaning of cure: **care for**. *Procure* then develops several derived meanings from its basic meaning: **Care in behalf of**. All of these derived meanings can be connected reasonably (though sometimes tortuously) to ***forward concern***.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but it seems: persuading someone to do something, or causing it to happen by some other means, demonstrates a **"forward concern"** that amounts to liability or culpability in crime. Or on the positive side it may demonstrate satisfying the considerations of a contract through an agent. Your rigid application of in *behalf of* seems to be problematic.